# When I send a value to my controller from my razor page, I get null

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I want to send data to my controller with `@Html.Hidden`, but it comes back as null. When I examine the code on the page with F12, I can see that the value is correct. But it comes as null to my controller.All my other data reaches my controller correctly, but this one goes null.And of course I tried this too :

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Repairs.kullaniciLog, new { value = usersDetails.username })
```

Razor :

```
@{
    var usersDetails = Session["UsersDetails"] as GAP_Bakim.Models.UsersDetails;
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Repairs", "Repair", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "repairSuccess" }))
 {  
    ................
    @Html.Hidden("kullaniciLog", usersDetails.username)
```

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Repairs(Repairs repairs)
```

Model :

```
 public class Repairs
{
  ......
  public string kullaniciLog { get; set; }
```

Comment: ASP.NET Razor does not support changing the "form context" within a page (which is a huge shortcoming IMO), so what's rendered is `<input type="hidden" name="Repairs.kullaniciLog" value="..." />` but what you want is `<input type="hidden" name="kullaniciLog" value="..." />`. There are workarounds but they're ugly - the quick-fix is to have a hardcoded `name=""` attribute.

Comment: I had to try this way because I couldn't find a solution.